# Map Two Data Frames to create a dictionary with multiple values for a key - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, mapping

I want to create a `dictionary` that will have multiple values for a key.

I have the following DataFrame `df1` like this:

```
    ID       SUM       COUNT
2   3002    256401.0    15
1   3021    5412.49     21
4   3022    45454.12    12
3   3025    15487.23    45
5   3026    154876.1    88
```

And I would like to map the ID's to the big lookup table to get multiple values for each ID. My other look up table `df2` looks like this,

```
    ID      Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4
0   3021    Cfd45   shkjs   shkjs   465
1   3021    sfs     None    fjslk   323
2   3021    hjfks   shka    fsad    457
3   3022    None    skank   vssf    236
4   3022    sdkj    vbjajl  bbf     124
5   3025    klgf    vcbj    jgjg    895
6   3026    tuo     None    gdsfs   457
7   3026    klo     ahk     None    569
8   3026    nbjd    alkdjl  sfsfs   124
```

Now, I want to map these two DataFrames by ID and create a dictionary that has unique ID and multiple values from `df2`'s `var1`, `var2` and `var3` columns,

```
{3021: ['Cfd45', 'shkjs', 'sfs', 'jkdg', 'fjslk', 'hjfks', 'shka', 'fsad'],
3022: ['skank', 'vssf', 'sdkj', vbjajl', 'bbf'],
3025: ...}
```

The values could be in a list or tuple.

For my scenario, the closest I could find was this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39197261/how-to-add-multiple-values-to-a-key-in-a-python-dictionary). However, I want values from multiple columns when I map to the table. How can I proceed with this? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let try this on df2:

```
df2.set_index('ID')[['Var1','Var2','Var3']].stack().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.unique()).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
    {3021: array(['Cfd45', 'shkjs', 'sfs', 'None', 'fjslk', 'hjfks', 'shka', 'fsad'], dtype=object),
 3022: array(['None', 'skank', 'vssf', 'sdkj', 'vbjajl', 'bbf'], dtype=object),
 3025: array(['klgf', 'vcbj', 'jgjg'], dtype=object),
 3026: array(['tuo', 'None', 'gdsfs', 'klo', 'ahk', 'nbjd', 'alkdjl', 'sfsfs'], dtype=object)}
```

OR

```
df2.set_index('ID')[['Var1','Var2','Var3']].stack().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.unique()).to_json()
```

Output:

```
'{"3021":["Cfd45","shkjs","sfs","None","fjslk","hjfks","shka","fsad"],"3022":["None","skank","vssf","sdkj","vbjajl","bbf"],"3025":["klgf","vcbj","jgjg"],"3026":["tuo","None","gdsfs","klo","ahk","nbjd","alkdjl","sfsfs"]}'
```

Comment: thank you! This is a good approach. However, I just need I only need `var1`, `var2` and `var3`. Also, I assume this approach will take lot of time when i have many records.

Comment: @i.n.n.m Okay, added the restriction for Var1, Var2, Var3

Comment: nice, had some other columns with about over a million record and it took long time. Now that I limit to columns, it works. I was trying this, here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44713968/pandas-dataframe-to-dict-on-multiple-columns-and-values-to-list/44713994#comment80198211_44713994. I guess, the difference is using `stack()` in your code to add multiple columns?

Comment: Yes, I am using stack() to align all thos Var's in to a single column the using the same technique as described in that SO post except I am getting unique values.